# Postman JSONError: No value found for key

Tags: json, postman

i have the following error when trying to read the JSON response in test script:

```
pm.test("JSON valid", function () { 
    var jsonData = pm.response.json(); 
    console.log(jsonData.deuda_total_anual);
    //pm.expect(jsonData.deuda_total_anual).eql(undefined);
});
```

The error appears in pm.response.json() because I have a field called:deuda_total_anual that depending on the case can be null.

This is the Body Response:

```
{
"estado":"OK",
"msj":"",
"municipios":[
      {
        "c_municipio":"28",
        "d_municipio":"DOS DE MAYO",
        "deuda_total_mensual":4421.25,
        "deuda_total_anual":
       }
    ]
}
```

I already looked for similar cases but did not find anything in the forums. Would you be so kind to help me please?

Comment: What happens if you use `let jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);`?

Comment: The example you provided isn't `null` it's empty and invalid JSON.

Comment: @DannyDainton thanks! that was the problem. In this website: https://jsonlint.com/ I was able to verify the exact line of the error, it tells me that it is an invalid json since it cannot be empty.